# Creating "Memory" In Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, memory, temp

I'm not sure how to word my question here. But for example, say I have a batch file with:

```
@echo off

echo test > text.txt
set example_var=<text.txt
```

I know that this specific piece of code is redundant since you could just set "example_var" equal to "test", but my question is how can I create "memory" (as in data that the text document holds) inside of the batch?

Something like this:

```
@echo off

echo test 0>&1
set example_var=<&1
```

Basically I just want to avoid creating temporary text documents to hold information. I am sure I found an example on this website before but I couldn't find it.

EDIT:

So this is the situation:

```
(%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Code.ps1) | find "::/kl" | set /p code
```

I want the output of `%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Code.ps1` and `find "::/kl"` to be the input for `set /p code`, ultimately setting a string of text to be put into the variable `code.`

Comment: Do you mean *"memory"* that persists between system reboots and successive runs of your script? Or *"memory"* just during the current invocation/run of your script?

Comment: I mean just in the current running script.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29589460/2861476) is the question you were looking for

Comment: MC ND - I don't think that was the one I saw before, but that still might work. I understood the accepted comment in that link except for one part:
"echo set "SendPath=%SendPath%" >> "%~F0"" I don't know what "%~F0" means, or how to use those variables with one percent sign.

Comment: `%0` is a reference to the batch file itself. `%~f0` is the batch file with full path. See `call /?` for the full list of argument modifiers

Comment: @MCND - Okay, I think I understand that now. But that only would result in the string being appended to the current batch. I'll show a little bit more of what I'm trying to do here. This is what I have:

(%systemroot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Code.ps1) | find "::/kl"

So I could add in something like:

if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (echo set code= > %~f0)

There are more characters in the line that it's finding behind "::kl" and I want it to copy the output of that first code and use it as code for something else. I don't have enough characters to explain better sorry.

Comment: @MCND - Basically, want to do this:

if "%errorlevel%"=="0" ((%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Code.ps1) | find "::/kl" | set /p code)

But it is not working.

Comment: Comments are too limited. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44475818/edit) your question to reflect your progress.

Comment: @MCND - Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipe approach will fail to set the variable for the current script because each of the commands in the pipe are running in separate processes.

The usual way to deal with the task of retrieving the output of a command into a variable is to use a `for /f` command

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    %systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Code.ps1
    ^| find "::/kl"
') do set "code=%%a"
```

Comment: I have seen that before, but just don't understand it. What is "delims="? And why is the "find" part of the code underneath with a upward carrot? I just used the code and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user8142044, read `for /?`. `for /f` tokenizes input lines using a list of delimiters, the `delims=` just clears the list of delimiters so the lines are not tokenized. `^|` is the escaped pipe character. The lines in the command enclosed in single quotes in the `for /f` will be concatenated to conform a single line, so you can separate the elements in the pipe to make reading easier.

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of cmd.exe inherits the environment from the starting process, which inherits from the master environment.
So you can store persistently in the master environment with [setx](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).

Or like you tried store single vars in a file and retrieve with

```
(Echo:%Example_var%)>text.txt
Set /p "Example_var="<text.txt
```

This will store only the content of the variable, or

```
(Set Example_var)>text.txt
For /f "delims=" %%A in (text.txt) Do Set %%A
```

Which stores/restores `variablename=variablecontent`

As a variation without specifying a variable name the latter could [store/restore the whole environment](https://superuser.com/a/1160326/639112).

Comment: So you're saying do something like:
setx var "example_var"
and then calling that later?

Comment: Yes he means initiate that and then reuse it

Comment: I could do that, and then remove the master variable afterwards. If nothing else works, I may just do that.